# phpmyadmin has stopped working

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

Yesterday I executed without problem the order`localhost/phpmyadmin` but since then, it does not work anymore. when I do`localhost/phpmyadmin` in my browser I just get a blank page.

here is my file `/var/log/apache2/error.log`:

```
[Wed Mar 14 23:49:47.718093 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3412] 
AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal 
operations
[Wed Mar 14 23:49:47.718156 2018] [core:notice] [pid 3412] AH00094: 
Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Mar 14 23:49:50.449163 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3412] 
AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Mar 14 23:49:50.547506 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3478] 
AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal 
operations
[Wed Mar 14 23:49:50.547550 2018] [core:notice] [pid 3478] AH00094: 
Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

help me understand what's wrong, please!

Comment: Check your PHP error log.

Comment: Have you tried accessing it via `https://localhost/phpmyadmin` or via ip address in place of local host? Is your `apache2` service running?

Comment: I tried `127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin` and i have 404 error.

Comment: @MichaelHampton /var/log/apache2/error.log would have shown any php errors.

Comment: @Mavis what do you find in your /etc/apache2 concerning php? I mean in the conf files.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille That depends on the PHP configuration, which wasn't specified here.

Comment: @Gerard H. Pille `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` contains apache configuration files

Comment: No kidding!!  Who would have expected that?!?   Can you please search those for anything related to PHP?  Is your PHP running via fastcgi?   Is fastcgi still active?

Comment: @Michael Hompton my php is set to display errors in `/var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: @Gerard H. Pille I just realized that `127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin` works properly but `localhost/phpmyadmin` always show me a blank page.

Comment: Can you ping "localhost"?

Comment: that's what ping on localhost gives me:                                                            `--- localhost ping statistics ---
56 packets transmitted, 56 received, 0% packet loss, time 56296ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.039/0.068/0.103/0.015 ms`

Comment: It didn't show an  IP address?

Comment: no! no ip adress

Comment: See my answer.   What version of Linux are you running?

Comment: I use kali-rolling.

Comment: Kali?  So you have lots of experience with networking?

Comment: not so much i hack little things from time to time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ ping localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.045 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.042 ms
^C
--- localhost ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.042/0.043/0.045/0.006 ms
```

The OP gets:

```
# ping localhost
PING localhost (localhost (:: 1)) 56 octets de données
64 octets de localhost (:: 1): icmp_seq = 1 ttl = 64 temps = 0.027 ms
64 octets de localhost (:: 1): icmp_seq = 2 ttl = 64 temps = 0.095 ms
```

He's trying to reach his server via IPv6, but his server is only configured for IPv4.

Comment: `~ # ping localhost PING localhost (localhost (:: 1)) 56 octets de données 64 octets de localhost (:: 1): icmp_seq = 1 ttl = 64 temps = 0.027 ms 64 octets de localhost (:: 1): icmp_seq = 2 ttl = 64 temps = 0.095 ms 64 octets de localhost (:: 1): icmp_seq = 3 ttl = 64 temps = 0.086 ms ^ C --- localhost ping statistiques --- 3 paquets transmis, 3 reçus, 0% perte de paquets , temps 2029 ms rtt min / moy / max / mdev = 0.027 / 0.069 / 0.095 / 0.030 ms `

Comment: Do you see now what your problem is?

Comment: in fact localhost displays (:: 1) as ip address and it's normal because it's my local ip address Ipv6 trying`ping -4 localhost`  it correctly displays my ipv4 address

Answer (score -1):

The problem is solved and that of the simplest and most stupid of the possible ways. I just uninstall and reinstall phpmyadmin and everything works again. Honestly, I do not know what happened first, but I'm working on it. For all those who would have a similar problem try this good old method, it almost always works.

Comment: OMG.  There's no need to follow this advice.